# I want to translate SQL to DQL

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, dql, symfony-2.7

I want to translate some SQL statement to DQL. I have user entity:

```
-------user--------
   id 
   username
   email
   password 
   ...
--------------------
```

and a friend entity which have 2 attribute friend_one and friend_two who reference to user

```
------friend---- 

   id 
   friend_one
   friend_two
   statu

--------------
```

so my SQL statement are

```
UPDATE friend
SET status="1"
WHERE 
(friend_one="$user_id" OR friend_two="$user_id") 
AND 
(friend_one="$friend_id" OR friend_two="$friend_id")
```

---

```
SELECT 'friend_one','friend_two','status' FROM friend
WHERE
(friend_one="$user_id" OR friend_two="$user_id")
AND
(friend_one="$friend_id" OR friend_two="$friend_id")
```

---

```
SELECT F.statu, U.username, U.id
FROM user U, friend F
WHERE
CASE
WHEN F.friend_one = '$user_id'
THEN F.friend_two = U.user_id
WHEN F.friend_two= '$user_id'
THEN F.friend_one= U.user_id
END
AND 
F.statu='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Good but have you actually tried anything so far? It would be great if you include your current code in the question.

I would suggest you something like these queries below:
(Disclaimer: please note they are quite raw and haven't been tested)

```
/* For update */
$result = $db->executeUpdate('UPDATE friend AS f SET f.status = "1" WHERE (f.friend_one = ? OR f.friend_one = ?) AND (f.friend_one = ? OR f.friend_two = ?)', 
            array($user_id, $user_id, $friend_id, $friend_id),
            array(\PDO::PARAM_INT, \PDO::PARAM_INT, \PDO::PARAM_INT, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
            );


/* For first select */
 $stmt = $db->executeQuery('SELECT f.friend_one, f.friend_two, f.status from friend AS f 
            WHERE (f.friend_one = ? OR f.friend_one = ?) AND (f.friend_one = ? OR f.friend_two = ?)', 
            array($user_id, $user_id, $friend_id, $friend_id),
            array(\PDO::PARAM_INT, \PDO::PARAM_INT, \PDO::PARAM_INT, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
            );

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();


/* For second select */     
 $stmt = $db->executeQuery('SELECT f.status, u.username, u.id from friend AS f 
        INNER JOIN user as u ON u.user_id =
        CASE WHEN f.friend_one = ? THEN f.friend_two WHEN f.friend_two = ? THEN f.friend_one END
        AND f.status = "1"', 
        array($user_id, $user_id),
        array(\PDO::PARAM_INT, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
        );

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [doctrine query Builder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.